# Iframe with pdf black flickering(blinking)

Tags: jquery, css, pdf, iframe, scroll

I have an iframe with pdf on my page and try to disable scrolling of main window while scrolling iframe. Here is the code for it:

```
$('iframe')
    .mouseover(function () {
        var html = $('html');
        html.data('previous-overflow', html.css('overflow'));
        html.css('overflow', 'hidden');
        html.css('margin-right', '17px');
    })
    .mouseout(function () {
        // un-lock scroll position
        var html = $('html');
        html.css('overflow', html.data('previous-overflow'));
        html.css('margin-right', '0px');
    });
```

But such css changes causing flickering of iframe content (using Chrome 13). 
How can i fix this blinking?

Comment: do you have an example page with the code running?

Comment: yep, host it here: http://dima.staticloud.com/
I use chrome without any pdf plugin

Comment: are you saying that if you disable the css changes the flickering doesnt happen? this seems to be an issue with chrome's PDF viewer

Comment: exactly: disable css changes and flickering stops. I have tried the same on dev-branch (ver. 15) on chrome and everything works fine there , so i think you are right and this is a bug of 13th version.

Comment: it works fine in Chrome16, however failed in Firefox9 ( pdf not shown, but saved as file)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work on all browsers and OS, the only way is to use custom scrollbars such as
[Tiny scrollbar](http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/) or you can take a loot at this scrollbars list http://www.net-kit.com/jquery-custom-scrollbar-plugins/.