# How to avoid blinking iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

```
<a href="#" id="toggle01">CONTACT</a>

<script>
$('#toggle01').click(function() {
    $('#contact').slideToggle("slow");
    return false;
});
</script>


<div id="contact">
123-456<br />
</div>
<iframe id="player" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/..."></iframe>
```

Everything works here, but when I click on link CONTACT and `div#contact` becomes visible/invisible, the iframe flashes and blinks.
How can I avoid this blinking ?

Comment: Could you show us the `slideToggle` plugin, what does it do?

Comment: This may be a possible answer to it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200425/iframe-with-pdf-black-flickeringblinking What do you want to use an iframe for though? You could also use a DIV with `overflow:auto;`
@Bergi slideToggle is a JQuery native function.

Comment: @IgnacioBelhotColistro, agree to your answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the hint - I didn't think it was the simple height-animation-toggle. @Alegro: I think the only possibilities are to use a stronger machine / a better browser or an animation that doesn't change the video-player's position.

Comment: @IgnacioBelhotColistro, do you say that I can use a div instead an iframe ? I have a youtube video in the frame.

Comment: @Bergi, I have a rather strong machine and Firefox 16.1

Comment: @Alegro Yes, you can perfectly use a DIV for that. Just set the DIV an ID and then with CSS set the overflow of it to auto. Here's an example that might help you: http://jsfiddle.net/2pajV/

Comment: @IgnacioBelhotColistro, yuo placed iframe inside a div. I did the same - the iframe flashes again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be the sliding animation. While your div is animated the iframe moves down and causes to be rerendered.

You could place your div after the iframe or encapsulate it within another div with a fixed height.

For example:

```
<div style="height:50px;">
    <div id="contact">
        123-456<br />
    </div>
</div>
```

But this will leave a blank area above your iframe.

Comment: I tried everything you said, without result. This is the address: `http://www.mementocosmicum.site90.net/`

Comment: your site works fine for me. only in IE it flashes a little bit, but this is browser specific and can't be fixed with a script, except rearranging your items.

Answer (score 1):

You script looks correct and i dont see any reason why it should blink. However Can you try the below script ? Add e.preventDefault();

```
<script>
   $('#toggle01').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#contact').slideToggle("slow");
     return false;
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot to put brackets. Corrected.

Comment: Abhishek, the iframe flashes again

Comment: I tested this and it doesnt flicker for me. Check properly your css and html tags.